# Javascript arrays: Given array[n], get array[n*m]

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'd like to know which would be the best way to solve this problem using javascripts native array methods(map,reduce,etc.).

Given an array of n objects I want to create another array that will contain m objects for each element in the original array. I can do it using common "for" loops to iterate the array but I'd like to know if it can be solved with the native array methods.

Example case:

I have an array with n elements of like "ObjectA":

```
var objectA = {
       name: "xxx",
       tels: ["yyy","zzz"]
};
```

I would like to get another array of objects of type "ObjectB":

```
var objectB = {
       name: "xxx",
       tel: "yyy"
};
```

So in this case, if the first array contained only objectA, the desired result would be:

```
[
   {
      name: "xxx",
      tel: "yyy"
   },
   {
      name: "xxx",
      tel: "zzz"
   }
]
```

I've tried using two nested "map" calls, but the callback function can only return one element.

```
var array1 = [objectA];

var array2 = array1.map(function(objectA){
   return objectA.tels.map(function(tel){
      return {
                 name : objectA.name,
                 tel : tel
              };
   });
});
```

Returning another array in the callback, generates an array of arrays and it's not what I want. Array2 result:

```
[
   [
      {
         name: "xxx",
         tel: "yyy"
      },
      {
         name: "xxx",
         tel: "zzz"
      }
   ]
]
```

Do I have to use common for loops or is there a native javascript way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) could not work with `array1` root here, because it returns an array of the same length, which is not what you want.

If you want another length you can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and then use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for each object tels.

```
var array2 = array1.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr.tels.map(function (tel) {
        return {name: curr.name, tel: tel};
    }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realised that reduce could use an array as initial value instead of a primitive. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah reduce is a powerful tool, but there are sometimes simpler ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your nested map, however as you noticed when you do that you will get arrays in arrays. To avoid that use forEach and push the results to an array in the inner loop instead:

```
var result = [];

initialArray.forEach(function(item){
   item.tels.forEach(function(tel){
      result.push({
          name : item.name,
          tel : tel
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: It's a good solution but I prefer @aduch's approach, it's kinf of more geek... XD Anyway, thanks!